# Array subscript out of range SAS

Tags: sql, arrays, loops, arraylist, sas

I have a dataset of 3 variables: id, date, and transaction amounts. I get the following error when I attempt to run this code:

```
DATA new;
SET old;
BY id date;
RETAIN dt1- dt400   amt1- amt400;
ARRAY TFL{400} dt1 - dt400;
ARRAY TAM{400} amt1 - amt400;
IF first.id THEN DO;
      CALL MISSING(of TFL{*});
      CALL MISSING(of TAM{*});
END;
z = INTCK('DAY', '31JUL2018'd,date);
TFL{z} = date;
TAM{z} = net_expenditure;
IF last.id THEN OUTPUT;
RUN;
```

Message:

> ERROR: Array subscript out of range at line 39 column 1.

How can I debug this issue?

Comment: Look at the log you will set the value of Z (your subscript) it will not be in the range 1-400.

Comment: @data_null_  the full error message in the log reads: ERROR: Array subscript out of range at line 39 column 1.

Comment: Well, which line is line 39?

Comment: @JoshEller  39         TFL{z} = date;

Comment: What are your dates? Like @data_null_ says, this will throw an error if `z` is out of the given range. In this case, that'll be for any dates earlier than 31JUL2018, or later than 04SEP2019.

Comment: @JoshEller the dates in the dataset range from july 1, 2018 to june 30, 2019

Comment: Well, there's your problem. When it process the row for July 1, 2018, `z` will be -30. That's outside the array boundaries. What you want to do here really depends on what you're trying to do overall.

Comment: Then why are you using `'31JUL2018'd` instead of `'30JUN2018'd` as your basis in the INTCK() function call?

Comment: makes sense!! I did not catch that. I was testing a dataset earlier that started in august. This solves the issue thanks!!

Comment: Curious... what are you doing with the data that is now a single row per `id` with 800 variables storing up to 400 date offset indexed transaction amount values ?